# windows 2016 failover cluster

Tags: windows-server-2016, high-availability, failovercluster

Windows 2016 Failover Cluster with two nodes, both nodes have subnet A and B physical interfaces, and a generic service defined with client access point on both subnet A and B.

Can I fail over from node 1 to node 2 when physical interface on node 1 fails on either subnet A or B?

I researched NIC teaming but per node I have 1 physical interface on subnet A and 1 physical interface on subnet B. I can't team the nics from different subnets.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can team interfaces and then create VLANs.

Check this out: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/keithmayer/2012/11/20/vlan-tricks-with-nics-teaming-hyper-v-in-windows-server-2012/